# Regex query in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to achieve the effect of following query in Hibernate, but I'm unable to figure out a way to do this.

```
select e.TITLE from EVENTS e where e.TITLE REGEXP 'fri|pro';
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate QL doesn't support regular expressions (and some engines have a very poor regexes support).
You can transform your query to be

```
select e.TITLE from EVENTS e where (e.TITLE = 'fri' OR e.TITLE = 'pro');
```

or

```
select e.TITLE from EVENTS e where e.TITLE in ('fri','pro');
```

But for *real* regex support you'll have to write custom SQL (if your DB does support regexes at all)

Comment: Thanks, but value in my column will be like this 'fri**pro' (** are just delimiters). How do I work out this?

Comment: `select e.TITLE from EVENTS e where e.TITLE like 'fri%pro' OR e.TITLE like '%fri%' OR e.TITLE like '%pro%'` 
Pick what "like" you like more :-) i.e. which one meets your conditions since they are still unclear.