# Use regex query with hibernate in Spring

Tags: java, mysql, regex, spring, hibernate

I am able to fire query in query browser (my sql) and able to retrieve record like below `SELECT *  FROM details WHERE title REGEXP 'dem'`;

but when I use similar type of code in server side then I is giving  error as unexpected token: REGEXP

After searching on web, it seems that hibernate does not support REGEXP. but some solution are also given which are not relevant to that. I need to handle this through query only in hibernate.

```
sbQuery.append("select distinct id from deatil id");
sbQuery.append("where ((id.title like :keyword) OR (id.description like :keyword) ");
```

Comment: Related : [Regex query in Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5831768/4290096)

Comment: Thanks for this, But for me this is not working because i need regex only. Workaround given i have already applied but these do not fulfilling my requirement else creating more issues. Any other way or suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1909410/4754790) in the Hibernate dialect for your database.

I tried adding a custom function that was a bit more complex than this and I had issues to make it work, hopefully the simpler ones should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select distinct id from deatil id where (id.title like :keyword) OR (id.description like :keyword)")
.setParameter("keyword", keyword);
List result = query.list();
```

Missing ")"  and must set parameter value.

Comment: This will not be treated as regex. Ex I have a string "My ARG Students are good to pay for application and content" I want to search good and then i need to put like in loop condition. To avoid this i want to use regex. In short keyword parameter can contain many different keyword.